# Counterexample to the product of subsets of a Lie Group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group. Given $H,K \subset G$, let $HK= \{ hk \mid h\in H, k \in K\}$

**Does the following hold?**

> If $H$ or $K$ is open then $HK$ is open. Also If $H$ and $K$ are compact then $HK$ is compact.

I tried finding counterexamples find I cant find any, clearly if we relaxed the condition that $G$ is not a Lie group then there are lots of counterexample. I also tried to prove it but I'm getting nowhere I've tried to used the smoothness but I'm still stuck.

Any hints and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Now I'm curious as to what your lots of counterexamples are, since one of the proposed answers below says that these facts are true in any topological group.

Answer (score 1):

Both claims are true in any topological group. For the first claim, assume $H$ is open. Then if $x \in HK$, then $x = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$, but then $Hk$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ that is contained in $HK$, so $HK$ contains an open neighbourhood of any of its points and hence is open. Similarly if $K$ is open. For the second claim, $HK$ is a continuous image of the compact set $H\times K$.

Answer (score 0):

If $H,K$ are compact, the product $H\times K$ with the product topology is compact. $f:H\times K\rightarrow G$ defined by $f(h,k)=hk$ is continuous, and its image $HK$ is compact since it is the image of a compact set by a continuous map.

Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are open, $H\times K$ are open $G\times G$ since the product $G\times G\rightarrow G$ is an open map, we deduce $HK$.

Comment: The first claim assumption is either $H$ or $K$ is open not both. I'm trying to use your argument if we let one of them is open.

Comment: $HK=\bigcup_{k\in K}Hk=\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$ is a union of open sets.